# MoveWindow API function Error: Form already displayed; can't show modally

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to resize an external application by using [MoveWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534(v=vs.85).aspx) API.
But every time, I get This Error: [Form already displayed; can't show modally (Error 400)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264460(v=vs.60).aspx)  .
Obviously, I don't care about modal and/or non-modal mode of the window, I just wanna resize it.
`MoveWindow()` function always returns `true`, but the error arise from target application.
I'm using `Windows 7 Home Edition`and `.Net 4.0`.
Can anyone leads me to the correct direction? or give me a clue?

Here is my code:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetLastError();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hWnd = FindWindow(null, "foodsoft_aminpardazco_1388");

        if (hWnd != null)
        {
            bool result = MoveWindow(hWnd, 0, 0, 100, 100, false);
            Console.WriteLine(result?"hooraaa!":"error:"+GetLastError());
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("eeeee");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The message tells me, you cannot show already displaying form in modal mode, So i wanna resize this window in non-modal mode. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Error 400 looks like it's [ERROR_THREAD_MODE_ALREADY_BACKGROUND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You aren't supposed to call `GetLastError()` directly from .net; instead, you're supposed to call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`. That will tell you the actual error. Also that error code you linked is for Office, not Windows. Use the Windows error list, as @LarsTech linked to. Windows error 400 makes no sense for `MoveWindow()` (it makes sense for [`SetThreadPriority()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277(v=vs.85).aspx), which .net might be calling internally).

Comment: If your call to `MoveWindow` always returns `true` (as you explain in your question), how do you know the error code? Your code certainly doesn't retrieve the last error code on success (and it shouldn't anyway, as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534.aspx)). Besides, a window should only be modified from the thread that owns it.

Comment: @andlabs is partly right, only *ever* check for errors when the winapi function returned *false*.  It probably didn't.

Comment: @HansPassant I had that originally but then noticed the code shown used a `?:` to decide whether to print the error and only does so when false. That being said, I wouldn't know if the P/Invoke declaration is wrong to the point that it would ruin the return value...

Comment: @HansPassant: That statement turned wrong in an attempt to simplify. Only ever check for a thread's last error code, when the documentation tells you to. There is no strict requirement for an API to fail, nor do all APIs set the last error code on failure.

Comment: No one cares about main error message!  It tells me, you cannot show already displaying form in modal mode, So i wanna resize this window in non-modal mode. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Rzassar we are trying to tell you that "form in modal mode" is *the wrong message*: you are looking at the wrong section of the documentation. You need to look at the Windows error codes section, not the Office error codes section. We are also trying to tell you that you are not even looking at the right error, because calling `GetLastError()` directly from .net will give you an entirely different last-error than the one that you expected. Change your code to call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` and report back with the **actual** error number that `MoveWindow()` returns, please.

Comment: @Rzassar even if the window you are trying to move around is an Office window, `MoveWindow()` is a Windows function, not an Office function, so it would return Windows errors, not Office errors. And the reason you can't use `GetLastError()` directly from .net is that the CLR will make lots of Windows API calls behind your back to do its internal machinery, such as garbage collection. By the time your code calls `GetLastError()`, the error returned from `MoveWindow()` has already been lost. In your case, .net might be calling `SetThreadPriority()`, yielding 400, which isn't about windows.

Comment: @Rzassar we want to help you fix your problem, but we can't because the information about your problem doesn't make any sense, so there's no way we can come up with a fix. Please don't think we are deliberately trying to be unhelpful or don't care or are being offensive; we're not, we do care and we want to help. Proper Windows error handling is easy to get wrong, so we're just trying to help correct any mistakes in the error handling not just to make your life easier, but also everyone else's, especially those who will come to this page in the future via Google.

Comment: @andlabs: @IInspectable: I really appreciate All of your kindness. The reason why i can't use `GetLastError()` was very helpful and I'll give it a try (i'm not at my computer right now) but, as i already mentioned, this error came from **target application**, Not from my code. I'll give your suggestions a try (when i arrive home). Thank you all.